# Can a post that was put on hold and looks to be closed be preserved for its historical, humorous or other merit, rather than disappear?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, deleting

This question came to mind when looking at a recent post [swirling hexagon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315732/swirling-hexagon) now on hold.  It seemed to me that this post, while likely to be closed and thereafter disappear, represents a precious example of TeX.SE humor, and should be somehow not permitted to electronically wither. Is there someplace where the "best hits" of TeX.SE reside?

Comment: What makes you think it will disappear? Questions with answers are not 'swept up'.

Comment: That's good.  I did not realize that once it had an answer it would be preserved.  The humor in it is delicious. Is there a "best hits" archive somewhere?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006

Comment: The question in question has a -1 score, does this mean that it will disappear in 30 days?

Comment: @AFeldman: Depends on the constellation of planets. It will be preserved only if all nine planets (yes,Pluto counts!) are aligned;-)

Comment: @AFeldman Take a look at  the link: it's got answers and this prevents deletion.

Comment: I did take a look at the link, and it was not immediately evident that it was -1 _plus_ no answers, I had at first blush thought it was deletion if -1 or if no answers unless it is locked.  Thank you for clearing that up for me. Thanks for the astronomical explanation @ChristianHupfer!

Comment: @AFeldman: You're welcome. But seriously, as Joseph already stated: A question with answers can't be deleted as well as an accepted answer can be deleted by its owner (until it gets unaccepted, of course)

Comment: @AFeldman: Actually, the relevant question has 4 downvotes and three upvotes ;-)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the question is closed to avoid nonsense answers to it (like [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315740/80509) one)? How this question will be tidied up?

Comment: Why do you think that's the reason it was closed? I take it the reason for closure is the stated reason: the question is unclear. I don't see any evidence it was closed due to a collective desire to quash additional humour or stymie the site's potential wits. If by 'tidied up', you mean 'delete the non-accepted answer', why should it be? If not, what do you mean? Next thing you'll be wanting to delete my triangles and donkeys! *<Wanders off grumbling...>*

Comment: @cfr Let me clarify: the questions is now closed for reasons "being unclear". However, it has an accepted answer. So at least the person who wrote the accepted answer - contrary to what is claimed - actually understood the question. But let's move on, and put aside this. Since the questions is now closed, it is impossible to add other answers to it, e.g. a non-tikz solution (which is rather customary in this site). What is the reason for this? Are we waiting for the OP to return and edit his answer nicely? Are they motivated to do so? Are we waiting for someone to edit the post instead the OP?

Comment: @Matsmath Thanks for clarifying. Now what you're asking makes sense to me. Ideally, the OP would edit the question. That may never happen. Somebody else could edit it. That's a bit tricky because edits shouldn't significantly alter the original meaning of a post and, in this case, the problem is that meaning isn't clear. I don't know whether it is OK to edit a question to fit the accepted answer, but I would suspect that generally it is not. However, if somebody actually wanted to provide e.g. an alternative solution, almost certainly a mod would oblige by reopening the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315743/5764) didn't receive the attention it has, then perhaps it may have been different, but the post won't be deleted, as [it doesn't fit the criteria laid out for deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/168244).

Reference(s):

- [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78048/168244)
- [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/168244) (FAQ)